# How to change a <li> bullet icon when hovering on a tag in it?

Tags: html, css

In my `<ul>` list I have several `<li>` with `<a>` tags in them.

I want to change the color of the li bullet icons when hovering on the `<a>` tag (I mean bullets beside `<li>`)

I tried

```
a:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

but it doesn't affect the`<li>` bullet icon.

I also tried

```
ul li:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

But it doesn't work perfectly because when mouse move to near `<a>` tag and not on it `<li>` and the bullets starts to change color.

Comment: Sounds like the links aren't `display:block` and aren't taking up the full size of the `li`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Provide the source code

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes and how i can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code actually worked for me.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">A</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">B</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">C</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li:hover{
  color:red;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tox9je8n/

Answer (score 1):

I have tried something related to your question and it works fine. To fix the issue of li:hover not hovering link, you should set  to display:block, as below, so that it takes full width.

```css
ul li a {
  color: black;
  display: block
}

ul li:hover {
  color: red;
}

ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Value 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Value 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Value 3</a></li>
</ul>
```